# Date filter is not working properly in magento 1

Tags: mysql, magento-1.9

Below code for getting order id for "From" & "to" date but when i execute it gets timeout as i have lots of orders in magento store.

I expect it should return order id of orders created
between the two input dates.

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/.."));
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::init();
Mage::app()->addEventArea('global');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();
        $orderItem->getSelect()
            ->joinInner(array('order' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), 'order.entity_id = main_table.order_id')
            ->where("order.created_at >= ?" AND "order.created_at <= ?", '2020-08-23' , '2020-08-25');
    
    print_r(array_unique($orderids));
```

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Please clarify 'not working'. What did you expect to see, what do you actually see, and what do the logs say? Please also elaborate on your debugging process so far.

Comment: Thanks i have updates question

Comment: Please show complete code. You're referring to `$orderids` which isn't anywhere populated in your snippet.

Comment: Your code still isn't showing how `$orderids` comes into existence.